# Load web page automatically when open any browser

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, mozilla

When I start any browser, the browser automatically load the web page given bellow,

http://www.nuesearch.com/?type=sc&ts=1467177363&z=dc4cb6fed564c32bd292b57gdz7q7mbg6m1mfzbgfg&from=eve0629&uid=WDCXWD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WMC3F302817528175

I am running windows 7.

How can I fix the problem.

I already check the installed programs and extensions of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In each browser you can configure the start page

1. Chrome

Hamburger Menu -> parameters -> Startup section can configure start page

2. Edge

... Menu -> Parameter -> Open with section can configure start page

But generally this start page is provide by a malware. I supect you install a malware without want it

Answer (score 0):

Good question, Md. Shougat Hossain. At the bottom of the browser is a link called "uninstall". Click it and it will send you to webpage, letting you uninstall from Google Chrome or Firefox. Here are the steps for uninstalling from Chrome.

1.Open Chrome explore.

2.Click “Customize and control Google Chrome” in the right-top of the page and   click "Setting".

3.Click “Set pages” link of "On startup" ->delete Nuesearch homepage link ->click “OK”.

4.Click "Change" link of "Apperance" ->delete Nuesearch homepage link ->click "OK".

5.Restart Chrome explore.

Restart your computer after completing all the above steps.